# Mass Crashes org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob -> java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException

Tags: android, crash, altbeacon

Getting thousands of crashes in android app:

App is in background

Crashes on LG & Motorola devices running android 10

Library version 2.16.3 ('org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.3')

Fatal Exception: java runtime exception
Unable to unbind to service org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@fe37965
OS Dead System Exception
Activity Thread handle Unbind Service (ActivityThread.java:4139)

Does anyone know a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication the OS has crashed and is dealing with cleaning up your app that happened to be running at the time of an unrelated crash.  Your app generally has no control over OS crashes.  The stack trace gives no clue as to the cause of the OS crash.

I imagine that this comes from an automated crash reporting system, so you probably cannot reproduce.  Given that this is an unknown OS crash outside your control and likely unrelated to your app, there is nothing you can do about it.

Bottom line: it is not your problem and you cannot fix it.  Please relay this information to whoever is asking you to do so.  And send feedback to whoever makes your crash reporting system that such stack traces should be filtered out of reports as they are unactionable noise.

Comment: I think it's better not to let the scan job to work in background unless it's inside a background service .

Comment: ScanJob is an instance of JobService which is how long running background processes are supposed to work k on Android 8+.  Read more here:  http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue. It seems that the altbeacon library in our app was actually triggering those crashes, and possibly crashing the OS in the process, but we resolved the issue by setting `setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false)` in the BeaconManager.